# How to change a label text color when pressed on a table view with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a cell that has 1 `UILabel` in it. I want the cell labels text color to change when the cell is pressed. How do I do that?

This is what I tried:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell

        let label:UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel
        label.textColor = UIColor(red: 46/255.0, green: 204/255.0, blue: 113/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        cell.reloadInputViews()



    }
```

Comment: label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

Comment: Do you want it to change only for the duration that the user is pressing it or to set the color permanently?

Comment: I want the text color to change when the cell is pressed, and when another cell is selected, i want it to change back.

Answer (score 3):

Subclass UITableViewCell and overwrite setSelected.

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
  if (selected) {
    label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
  } else {
    label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
  }
}
```

Comment: I get an error... Please answer with some code in a 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' function.

Comment: It is another apporach, by subclassing the cell.

Comment: I don't want to use that approach, Please use the 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' approach .

Comment: Please give an answer in a 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' function, then i will upvote your answer.

Comment: Thanks for answear! It's help me.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the didDeselectRowAtIndexPath delegate method. In this method you should set the label back to the normal color.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
  let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
  let label: UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel
  label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
  let label: UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel
  label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

Also, remove .reloadInputViews() unless you actually need it. This is probably wiping any updating of textColor.

Comment: But it cant seem to change the labels text color in the first place?

Comment: My mistake, are you sure you're setting the label's tag correctly? Setting the .textColor property should cause a refresh and update the color.

Comment: What are you using reloadInputViews for?

Comment: I removed reloadInputViews, and it still won't work. Please test you code in xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 version looks like:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    if (selected) {
         self.artistLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    } else {
         self.artistLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

just mention that this is much clear and better way to do it than in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

What I generally uses for such situations is overriding `setHighlighted` in `UITableViewCell` subclass as:

```
override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
    label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

For this, you have to use custom table view cells to override particular method.